# dyld: dyld_sim not compatible mach-o xcode 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I am trying to run my existing application in ios 11 simulator and when i run am getting "**dyld: dyld_sim not compatible mach-o**" error. only one line error in debug console can anyone help to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: iOS 11 doesn't support 32bit applications anymore, so i think that's problem.